# Should I flag posts that need formatting

Tags: support, review, flags, code-formatting

Having under 2k rep, how should I go about editing posts that simply failed to format their code block? By this I mean either haven't

1. Indented the code so it is shown as a block of code, rather it is shown all on a single line
2. Haven't put a free line between their code block and paragraph so a whole block of text doesn't get displayed at all
3. Haven't used `'s to show inline code

Generally these major issues (particularly the first 2) with the post take less then the required number of characters to fix.

Should I simply flag these posts under 'other' and state they need code formatting? Additionally, if these are spotted while reviewing, should they be flagged, or skipped - as in, are reviews seen by multiple users, and could be spotted by someone with +2k rep who can fix it themselves, or does skipping kick the post out of the review stack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**. Do not flag these posts. Flagging a post as other brings it to the moderators attention, and this is **not** something they should be handling (they are busy enough as it is).

The best thing you could do here is to simply leave the post. Someone with 2k+ privileges *will* come across the post eventually and fix it.

You *could* leave a comment on the post if you wanted to, but the best way to teach a new user here (IMO) is by example (i.e. letting them see the markdown diff of the changes made), rather than trying to explain to them where to add new lines via a comment.

In the review queue, again; I recommend you don't flag. Skip them or leave a comment. Skipping a post does nothing to it apart from not-showing it to you again; it's sort of like:

> I don't know how to (or can't) handle this post, so I'll skip it and let someone else take care of it.

... but AFAIK, *all* review queues require more than one reviewer (citation needed).

Comment: If someone improve a post (at least in the suggested edit queue), one reviewer can decide everything.

Comment: They can also suggest an edit, no matter their reputation level. If it's a good change to the formatting (please don't randomly format words within the body text of a post) it most likely will be approved under review. You'll even get a couple of points of reputation for doing so.